# Reinstalled WAMP, Wordpress Tables Not Found BUT Are in PHPMYADMIN

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

OK strange situation and I hope I am not just out of luck.  I upgraded from Windows 7 to 8 and when I did WAMP would not work.  I reinstalled WAMP not thinking and followed instructions online to get WAMP working.

Now though my Wordpress site redirets me to the install page.  When I go into phpmyadmin it looks like all of my tables are there but when I click on the wordpress database is says "No tables found in database".  If I click on one of the tables listed under wordpress it gives me the error "Table 'wordpress.wp_postmeta' doesn't exist"

I check my database files and they obviously contain data by the file sizes.

See the screenshots.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I was redoing our business website and would prefer not to have to start from scratch.

[image: Wordpress Database]

[image: Clicking on wp_posts table]

[image]

Comment: have you check your `config.php` file and check whether the correct database is being used?

Comment: It is using the correct database.  The problem is that its like the Database tables are there but are not there.

Comment: I had the same issue recently on OSX. I don't have the reference anymore, but I think the solution was on [su] (surely for Windows too). Looks like you haven't copy all the necessary files.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the problem were the old files:

```
ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ibdata1.
```

One should also backup them, close WAMP, copy, paste and remove the ones generated by the installation. After that phpMyAdmin recognises the tables we had prior to the reinstallation of WAMP!

Comment: Not sure why this got down-voted. Is an applicable solution to the problem described.

Comment: Thank you very much, save my data. Don't jnow why it been down-voted too.

Answer (score 0):

When you reinstalled WAMP you I assume put it into a new folder or you backed up the original wamp install.

If you did then you can copy the oldwamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\data\database_name into the newwamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z\data\database_name

Assuming you installed the same version this should be all you need to do.

For future reference or when you upgrade to Windows 8.1 all you actually needed to do, assuming the \wamp folder is not destroyed by the upgade is reinstall the Apache(wampapache) and MySQL(awampmysql) services, which are messed up by the install.

So just start wampmanager and then :-

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install Service
```

Comment: Unfortunately I did not install into a different directory.  All of my database files are still there though with large sizes yet in phpmyadmin they are empty.

Comment: I had the same issue & found that I had not copied all the necessary files from the mysql databases. Specifically `ib_logfile0`, `ib_logfile1`, `ibdata1`. The files are located in `wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/data`. Hope this helps at all.